# thread for I/O JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I need to be running an application in JavaFX, but at the same time have a thread listening inputs and outputs (I/O), for example lighting a bulb.

But to query the database from the application, the thread I/O is interrupted milliseconds.
Someone can help me with an example of a yarn having a higher priority to the application. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain it in other words?

Comment: @fabian we could use your dupe hunt skills in [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) just ping me or Tunaki .... and thanks :p